# Anchor tag not working properly in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, anchor, href

in aspx

```
 <a id="anchorViewMore" runat="server" > View More</a>
```

in backend c#

```
 anchorViewMore.HRef = "www.google.com";
```

output im getting
http://localhost:3180/seoapp%20april%2017%20keyword%20assign%20by%20TL%20-%20backup/www.google.com

i want that href should be only "google.com" and should redirect to that website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
anchorViewMore.HRef = "http://www.google.com";
```

If you don't put the 'http://' then it will link relative to the page you are on.

To make it open in a new window, you need to change the HTML to:

```
<a id="anchorViewMore" runat="server" target="_blank"> View More</a>
```

Comment: yes it worked how to open it in new window ,not in same window@user1578653